# Does not get all environment variables using getenv()

Tags: php, environment-variables

I want to print out all environment variables and their variable name, so ge would get something like

> PATH: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

for all environment variables, even the undefined ones. I created an array `$array = getenv();` and have used the following foreach loop:

```
<table>
    <?php
    $array = getenv();
    foreach ($array as $key => $item):  ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $key, ': ', $item; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

The problem is that I only get five environment variables through that (`XPC_SERVICES_UNAVAILABLE`, `OBJC_DISABLE_INITIALIZE_FORK_SAFETY`, `XPC_SERVICE_NAME`, `PATH` and `XPC_FLAGS`). First I thought that they were all defined environment variables, but if I add `echo getenv('SERVER_SOFTWARE');` after the loop, I get the value for that!

Does anyone know why I don't get all defined environment variables with my solution, and how to change it so I get the undefined ones as well? I have php version 7.3.8.

Comment: PHP version...?

Comment: 7.3.8, I will add that to the post!

Comment: What do you mean by "even the undefined ones"? If it's not defined, how would `getenv()` know about it?

Comment: If they don't have a value, I would like if it wrote something like `QUERY_STRING: ` if it doesn't have a value (so leave it blank). But then I should probably use `$_ENV` instead? I tried with getenv() because $_ENV is empty for me, but I can tell that there are more defined environment variables than the ones my `foreach` loop is giving me.